# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int with CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have query with `CASE WHEN` which condition with query below:

```
select 
CASE 
    WHEN DATE_ONE > 0 THEN 'ALREADY'
    WHEN DATE_TWO > 0 THEN 'PENDING'
    ELSE 'TBA' END AS ETA
,PH
from FactTable
```

ONE_DATE and TWO_DATE is has Date format column but the result error with detail:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the error self explanatory? You can't compare a date to 0 (what date is 0)?

Comment: @Dale K This is not the most absolute point in sql server. Dateadd(day,0,0) works, and confusions can easily stem from there.

Comment: @George these "tricks" work on datetime datatype but not on date or datetime2.

Comment: Define the expected behavior of comparing date with 0.

Comment: @Salman A Learned a new thing today, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 is an `int` and you are trying to compare it with a `date`.

Either you could try to pick a date ('1900-01-01') or work with null values to make a valid comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare with day number in CASE statement, use like below:

```
select 
CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(DAY,DATE_ONE) > 0 THEN 'ALREADY'
    WHEN DATEPART(DAY,DATE_TWO) > 0 THEN 'PENDING'
    ELSE 'TBA' END AS ETA
,PH
from FactTable
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: But if he wants to compare with day number , the above query will work. I have tested

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work, I just said you are using incorrect terminology.